# No puedo exportar datos de un exel a una base de datos laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

lo que quiero es seleccionar un archivo en exel y poder guardar esos datos en una tabla en la base de datos  este es el error que me tira
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi formulario

```
 {{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'#','name'=>'f_cargar_datos_usuarios','id'=>'f_cargar_datos_usuarios','method'=>'post','action'=>'cargar_datos_usuarios','class'=>'formarchivo','files'=>'true'))}}

                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    {!! Form::label('datos', 'Datos Usuarios:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {!! Form::file('archivo',['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'archivo']) !!}
                    </div>

                </div>

                <br>
                <br>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"   id="enviar">CARGAR DATOS</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {{Form::close()}}
```

este es mi js en el cual yamo ala ruta

```
$(document).on("submit", ".formarchivo",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formu = $(this);
    var nombreform = $(this).attr("id");

    if (nombreform == "f_cargar_datos_usuarios") {
        var miurl = "cargar_datos_usuarios";
        var divresul = "notificacion_resul_fcdu"
    }

    var formData = new FormData($("#" + nombreform + "")[0]);


    $.ajax({
            url: miurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,

            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,


            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#" + divresul + "").html($("#cargador_empresa").html());

            },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#" + divresul + "").html(data);

            },

            error: function (data) {
                alert("ha  ocurrido un error");
            }
        });
});
```

estas son mis dos rutas una para llamar la vista y el otro para enviar los datos

```
Route::get('cargar_empleados',[
    'as'=>'cargar_empleados',
    'uses'=>'importar_exel@cargar_empleados'
]);
Route::post('cargar_datos_usuarios',[
    'as'=>'cargar_datos_usuarios',
    'uses'=>'importar_exel@cargar_datos_usuarios'
]);
```

y este es mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\empleado;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Store;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

class importar_exel extends Controller
{
    public static function cargar_empleados(Request $request)
    {

        return \View::make('vista_exel.importar_datos_exel');
    }
    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {

        \DB::beginTransaction();
     $archivo=$request->file('archivo');
     $nombre_original=$archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $extension=$archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $rl=Store::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original,\File::get($archivo));
     $ruta=storage_path('archivos')."/".$nombre_original;

     if ($rl){

         Excel::selectScheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta,function ($hoja){
             $hoja->each(function ($fila){
                 $usersemails=User::where("identidad","=",$fila->identidad)->firs();
                 if (count($usersemails)==0){
                     $empleados=new empleado();
                     $empleados->nombre=$fila->nombre;
                     $empleados->identidad=$fila->identidad;
                     $empleados->num_empleado=$fila->num_empleado;
                     $empleados->fecha_nacimiento=$fila->fecha_nacimiento;
                     $empleados->direccion=$fila->direccion;
                     $empleados->telefono=$fila->telefono;
                     $empleados->celular=$fila->celular;
                     $empleados->nacionalidad=$fila->nacionalidad;
                     $empleados->correo=$fila->correo;
                     $empleados->nivel_academico=$fila->nivel_academico;
                     $empleados->titulo_obtenido=$fila->titulo_obtenido;
                     $empleados->rtn=$fila->rtn;
                     $empleados->ihss=$fila->ihss;
                     $empleados->certificado_seguro=$fila->certificado_seguro;
                     $empleados->genero=$fila->genero;
                     $empleados->estado_civil=$fila->estado_civil;
                     $empleados->departamento=$fila->departamento;
                     $empleados->municipio=$fila->municipio;
                     $empleados->tipo_contratacion=$fila->tipo_contratacion;
                     $empleados->ano_contratacion=$fila->ano_contratacion;
                     $empleados->gerencia=$fila->gerencia;
                     $empleados->unidad_ejecutora=$fila->unidad_ejecutora;
                     $empleados->actividad_obra=$fila->actividad_obra;
                     $empleados->puesto=$fila->puesto;
                     $empleados->dept_icf=$fila->dept_icf;
                     $empleados->banco=$fila->banco;
                     $empleados->no_cuenta=$fila->no_cuenta;
                     $empleados->pin=$fila->pin;
                     $empleados->vigencia=$fila->vigencia;
                     $empleados->no_contrato=$fila->no_contrato;
                     $empleados->sueldo=$fila->sueldo;
                     $empleados->sindicato=$fila->sindicato;
                     $empleados->lugar_nacimiento=$fila->lugar_nacimiento;
                     $empleados->descripcion_funciones=$fila->descripcion_funciones;
                     $empleados->forma_pago=$fila->forma_pago;
                     $empleados->lugar_recibe_pago=$fila->lugar_recibe_pago;
                     $empleados->estado_empleado=$fila->estado_empleado;
                     $empleados->save();
                     \DB::commit();
                 }
             });
         });
         return view("mensajes.msj_correcto")->with("msj","Usuarios cargados con exito");
     }
     else
     {
         return view("mensajes.msj_rechazado")->with("msj","Error al subir archivo");
     }


    }


}
```

Comment: te falta el files=>true, en tu formulario...

Comment: se lo agregue ahorita pero me sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: ahorita modifique el archivo no se cual puede ser el problema ahi le agregue la respuesta y le agregue lo que me dijiste en el formulario

Comment: me faltaba agregar el js podrias verificarlo porfavor

Comment: y si tan solo cambias `Store` por `\Store`

Comment: si se lo coloco asi entonces me tira Class 'Store' not found

Comment: el problema que tengo hasta ahorita es en el js por que comente el controlador y me tira el ese error ala hora que realizo el submit

Comment: perdon cambia Store::disk  por `Storage::disk` el problema no es en el ajax es en el lado del serve

Comment: este error me tira ahora message Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::selectScheetsByIndex()
exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
file D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\app\Http\Controllers\importar_exel.php

Comment: tienes configurado tu aliases en el archivo config/app.php? en tu controlador solo deberias de llamar `use Excel` y no lo que tienes tu

Comment: este es el que tengo en aliases 'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,  y este es mi provider   Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,

Comment: al parecer no me esta detectando ese metodo

Comment: en tu controlador tienes `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;` cambialo solo por `use Excel`

Comment: message Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::selectScheetsByIndex() me sigue tirando este problema

Comment: estoy utilizando laravel 5.4 esto influira

Comment: y me instala la version ^3.1 de Maatwebsite\Excel\